# Is there a statistically sound method of smoothing a data series without removing the edges?

Tags: time-series, smoothing, moving-average

Recently I've been plotting a lot of data, and often I find myself using a moving average to smooth out values that oscillate or otherwise fluctuate a lot. However, the problem with this is that it removes the edges of the series, so in case of e.g. up-to-date time-series data I no longer have a view of the most recent development (say I do a 30-day smoothing, and now ~2 weeks are gone from the beginning and end of the series).

Here's some data I'm looking at, for example:

[image]

Here there's a very clear ~monthly oscillation that I'd like to smooth out, but preferably without losing the last weeks or month of data. So, as the question says, are there any good methods of doing this? And if so, what are they and how do they work?

Comment: When a function clips the ends of a series, it is sometimes helpful to join the ends of the data so that it is effectively an endless loop. Not sure that helps with your data though. (Do you know that a running mean will change the phase of regular oscillations (i.e. delay them) while it smooths?)

Comment: I don't see how you can join the ends here, seeing as this is time-series data which doesn't have any overall repeating pattern, just certain somewhat irregular smaller-scale oscillations, so it should be fairly obvious from looking at the plot above that the ends don't join up anywhere; and I can't predict the future. As for a moving average changing the phase of such oscillations, I can't say that's anything I've observed, no. I don't really see how that's relevant to the question either.

Comment: The change of phase of the signal may not matter, but you do not say what you will be doing with the smoothed results and there are many purposes for which changes to the start and end time of the oscillations would matter.

Comment: @MichaelLew: I just want to see what the overall movement of the graph is more clearly; when I do e.g. 365-day smoothing, the oscillations are almost completely gone, but 182 days of data is then lacking on each side, whereas when I do 30-day smoothing as in the above plot, it's certainly better than with no smoothing, but still not that clear; and there's ~2 weeks lacking on each side again too. Also, another point to consider is that I'm not sure whether the oscillation period in question is entirely regular either, but it seems to be of around ~1 month.